# How to pass a "url with parameters" as a url parameter in GWT

Tags: gwt, url-encoding

I am calling a servlet from GWT client code using RequestBuilder.

In the request (a POST) I am passing some request data

builder.sendRequest(postData, new RequestCallback()....

In the postData I have a url parameter called "returnToUrl"

This "returnToUrl" has url parameters, and would be like this

```
returnToUrl = "http://my.server/add?pn=a&pd=b";
```

When I pass it to the servlet, the second (and later) parameters (pd=b in my example) get interpreted as request parameters for the servlet, not as part of the returnToUrl parameter, and hence get lost....

It is being URL encoded, but of course that doesn't change the '?' and '&' characters.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: That depends on your definition of URL encoding. For instance, JavaScript provides two methods, encodeURI (which only encodes illegal URI characters) and encodeURIComponent (which encodes the string into something that can be used as a parameter).

Comment: I am using URL.encode() in GWT, which corresponds to your first example. Is there a GWT class/binding for encodeURIComponent? If not I'll write a JSNI to do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode your data in GWT.

Take a look at the URL class to do this: 
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html

escpecially at encodeQueryString which basically has the same behaviour as encodeURIComponent in javascript.

Comment: Excellent, that works. Thanks Daniel. I *think* I was looking at an older version of the Javadoc for URL. Either way I didn't see that method, and it's a life saver... thanks again.